# bash sort and paste columns in alphabetical order

Tags: bash, awk

I have a `file.txt` which has the following columns

```
id  chr pos alleleA alleleB
1   01  1234    CT  T
2   02  5678    G   A
3   03  8901    T   C
4   04  12345   C   G
5   05  567890  T   A
```

I am looking for a way of creating a new column so that it looks like : `chr:pos:alleleA:alleleB`
The problem is that alleleA and alleleB should be sorted based on:
1. alphabetical order
2. either of these two columns with more letter per line should be first and followed by the second column

In this example , it would look like this :

```
id  chr pos alleleA alleleB newID
1   01  1234    CT  T   chr1:1234:CT:T
2   02  5678    G   A   chr2:5678:A:G
3   03  8901    T   C   chr3:8901:C:T
4   04  12345   C   G   chr4:12345:C:G
5   05  567890  T   A   chr5:567890:A:T
```

I appreciate any help and suggestion. Thanks.

**EDIT**
Up to now i can modify `chr` column so that it will have a look as "`chr:1`"...

`AlleleA` and `AlleleB` columns should be combined so that if either of columns contains more than 1 letter, in column `newID` it would be in the first place. If there is only one letter in both columns, these letters are arranged alphabetically in the `newID` column

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Please, explain the ordering in more details. Your sample doesn't illustrate the issues as sorting the alleles alphabetically is enough to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk 'function custom_sort(i1,v1,i2,v2){   # custom function to compare 2 crucial fields
         l1=length(v1); l2=length(v2);    # getting length of both fields
         if (l1 == l2) { 
             return (v1 > v2)? 1:-1  # compare characters if field lengths are equal
         } else { 
             return l2 - l1          # otherwise - compare by length (descending)
         }   
     } NR==1 { $0=$0 FS "newID" }  # add new column
       NR>1 { a[1]=$4; a[2]=$5; asort(a,b,"custom_sort"); # sort the last 2 columns using function `custom_sort`
       $(NF+1) = sprintf("chr%s:%s:%s:%s",$1,$3,b[1],b[2])
     }1' file.txt | column -t
```

The output:

```
id  chr  pos     alleleA  alleleB  newID
1   01   1234    CT       T        chr1:1234:CT:T
2   02   5678    G        A        chr2:5678:A:G
3   03   8901    T        C        chr3:8901:C:T
4   04   12345   C        G        chr4:12345:C:G
5   05   567890  T        A        chr5:567890:A:T
```

Comment: spasibo! awk is what i was looking for actually :)

Comment: @ThePooh, будьласка! )

Comment: Prosti, a esli u menya bolshe chem 5 columns, how can i print them all automatically without sprintf? :)

Comment: @ThePooh, `sprintf` даёт нам более наглядное и гибкое форматирование, иначе прийдётся брать в кавычки каждый разделитель

Comment: t.e. `sprintf` vse columns vozmet?

Comment: @ThePooh, не возьмёт. Здесь нужно понимать, где будут расположены дополнительные колонки: будут они между `id` и `chr` или между `pos` и `alleleA`

Comment: spasibo bolshoe :) poprobuu modificirovat

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lane '
    if (1 == $.) { print "$_ newID" }
    else { print "$_ ", join ":", "chr" . ($F[1] =~ s/^0//r),
                                  $F[2],
                                  sort { length $b <=> length $a
                                         or $a cmp $b
                                  } @F[3,4];
    }' -- input.txt
```

- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to `print`
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each input line on whitespace into the @F array
- `$.` is the input line number, the condition just prints the header for the first line
- `s/^0//` removes the initial zero from $F[1] (i.e. column 2)
- `/r` returns the result of the substitution
- the last two column lenghts are compared, if they are the same, string comparison is used.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations!